# Launch spring-boot app before Gatling simulation

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gatling

I have a spring-boot project powered by maven I would like to run load tests on, using Gatling.
At this moment, I can run my simulation typing the following command :

```
mvn gatling:execute
```

It works correctly but I have to launch my springboot app manually or it won't work.

Here is my Simulation class :

```
package main.aperture.gatling

import aperture.config.SpringBootApertureTestingConfiguration
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.structure.ScenarioBuilder
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.protocol.HttpProtocolBuilder
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

/**
  * This class is meant to load test main get routes of this app
  * The app has to be launched first (Manually, unfortunately)
  */
class MainSimulation extends Simulation {

    val baseUrl: String = "localhost"
    val port: String = System.getProperty("server.port", "8080")

    val httpConf: HttpProtocolBuilder = http
        .baseURL(s"http://$baseUrl:$port") // Here is the root for all relative URLs

    val scenario_main_get: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Testing main get routes")
        .exec(http("Request on main route")
            .get("/"))
        .pause(100 milliseconds)
        .exec(http("Request on rooms main route")
            .get("/api/rooms"))
        .pause(100 milliseconds)
        .exec(http("Request on subjects main route")
            .get("/api/subjects"))
        .pause(100 milliseconds)
        .exec(http("Request on supervisors main route")
            .get("/api/supervisors"))
    setUp(scenario_main_get.inject(rampUsers(1000) over (5 seconds)).protocols(httpConf))
}
```

Here is my *pom.xml* (I deleted unrelevant elements) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-accessing-mongodb-data-res</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- Properties -->
    <properties>
        <springfox-version>2.6.1</springfox-version>
        <springfox-swaggerui-version>2.6.1</springfox-swaggerui-version>
        <spring-version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <swagger-core-version>1.5.10</swagger-core-version>
        <slf4j-version>1.6.3</slf4j-version>
        <junit-version>4.8.1</junit-version>
        <hibernate-validator-version>5.2.4.Final</hibernate-validator-version>
        <fizzedwatcher.version>1.0.6</fizzedwatcher.version>
        <gatling.version>2.2.5</gatling.version>
        <gatling-plugin.version>2.2.4</gatling-plugin.version>
        <scala-maven-plugin.version>3.2.2</scala-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- Project dependencies  -->
    <dependencies>

        <!-- SpringBoot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Gatling highcharts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
            <version>${gatling.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <!-- Project build options and plugins -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!--Spring boot plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>aperture.config.SpringBootApertureTestingConfiguration</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Scala maven plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${scala-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Gatling maven plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gatling-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <simulationClass>main.aperture.gatling.MainSimulation</simulationClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I would like to be able to automatically run the spring-boot app before running the load tests with gatling. 
Some have suggested to add the following code at the beggining of my simulation :

```
val app: ConfigurableApplicationContext = SpringApplication.run(classOf[SpringBootApertureTestingConfiguration])

Runtime.getRuntime.addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    override def run(): Unit = app.stop()
})
```

But when I do that, I get the following error when I execute it :

```
[INFO] --- gatling-maven-plugin:2.2.4:execute (default-cli) @ gs-accessing-mongodb-data-res ---
20:32:23,625 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
20:32:23,625 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
20:32:23,625 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/home/msb/.m2/repository/io/gatling/gatling-maven-plugin/2.2.4/gatling-maven-plugin-2.2.4.jar!/logback.xml]
20:32:23,634 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@1a04f701 - URL [jar:file:/home/msb/.m2/repository/io/gatling/gatling-maven-plugin/2.2.4/gatling-maven-plugin-2.2.4.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
20:32:23,670 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
20:32:23,674 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
20:32:23,678 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [CONSOLE]
20:32:23,681 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@5:19 - no applicable action for [immediateFlush], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][immediateFlush]]
20:32:23,682 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
20:32:23,721 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - ROOT level set to WARN
20:32:23,721 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[ROOT]
20:32:23,722 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
20:32:23,722 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@4e91d63f - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

20:32:29,151 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
20:32:29,152 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
20:32:29,152 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/home/msb/.m2/repository/io/gatling/gatling-maven-plugin/2.2.4/gatling-maven-plugin-2.2.4.jar!/logback.xml]
20:32:29,169 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@5419f379 - URL [jar:file:/home/msb/.m2/repository/io/gatling/gatling-maven-plugin/2.2.4/gatling-maven-plugin-2.2.4.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
20:32:29,221 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
20:32:29,225 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
20:32:29,233 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [CONSOLE]
20:32:29,239 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@5:19 - no applicable action for [immediateFlush], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][immediateFlush]]
20:32:29,241 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
20:32:29,282 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - ROOT level set to WARN
20:32:29,282 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[ROOT]
20:32:29,282 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
20:32:29,283 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@7dc7cbad - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

main.aperture.gatling.MainSimulation is the only simulation, executing it.
Select simulation id (default is 'mainsimulation'). Accepted characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, - and _

Select run description (optional)

20:33:42.287 [restartedMain][WARN ][SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:91] o.s.b.SpringApplication - Error handling failed (no error message)
20:33:42.291 [restartedMain][ERROR][SpringApplication.java:839] o.s.b.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@5:19 - no applicable action for [immediateFlush], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][immediateFlush]]
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:161)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reinitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:205)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:65)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:114)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:299)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:272)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:235)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:208)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:68)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:337)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
        at main.aperture.gatling.MainSimulation.<init>(MainSimulation.scala:20)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at io.gatling.app.Runner.run0(Runner.scala:79)
        at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:64)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:59)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:43)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:35)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
        at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler$SilentExitException
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler.exitCurrentThread(SilentExitExceptionHandler.java:90)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.immediateRestart(Restarter.java:182)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:161)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartedEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:68)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:45)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:63)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.started(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
        at main.aperture.gatling.MainSimulation.<init>(MainSimulation.scala:20)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at io.gatling.app.Runner.run0(Runner.scala:79)
        at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:64)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:59)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:43)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:35)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
        ... 6 more
```

Maybe I forgot something or there is something missing in my configuration, but I can't find any help for my specific problem in the documentation. Some say it is a spring-boot dev tools bug.

Does anyone know how to correct this?

Even if my simulation is in a package inside my spring-boot project, It does not mean it is linked to the project. So, maybe it is not relevant to want to launch it directly in the code. However, has anyone found a workaround ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered wrapping this in a simple shell script and starting the app from the spring boot maven plugin?

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.3.RELEASE/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html.

Otherwise you should be able to hook the spring boot plugin into the maven lifecycle to run before gattling as well without a shell script.

Comment: I'll try to create a custom lifecycle and get back to you if it worked. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Well finally, the shell script looks like the better solution for now, as I don't want gatling tests to be part of the maven lifecycle. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Glad to help. A couple of suggestions you could probably simplify your script by using mvn spring-boot:start rather then spring-boot run. This should avoid you having to background the process and loop until it starts. You can then use mvn spring-boot:stop to stop the process after your tests have finished executing. Check out this link for some more details https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html. I would also add set -e and set -x to the start of your script to simplify debugging if things go wrong.

Comment: You could also override the port defined in your application.yml and pass this in when starting your app to avoid having to extract it with awk. i.e. mvn spring-boot:start -Dserver.port=8080

Comment: The documentation you mentioned helped me editing my pom.xml to start the app before launching tests, but only for a `mvn clean install` command. Still, this is the behaviour I expected. Thanks again !

Comment: The configuration you added should work for `mvn verify` as well right?

Comment: Yes it does. I think I'll read a few things about maven goals and lifecycle to fully understand how this works. I am pretty sure I am don't understand everything perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for something similar and found this to work:

`mvn spring-boot:start gatling:test spring-boot:stop`

Starting the application in the `before` hook also works.
This has the benefit you can set app configuration like urls to external services which then could be mocked e.q. with WireMock:

In Simulation class, add:

```
  before {
    val app = SpringApplication.run(classOf[Application])
    app.registerShutdownHook()
  }
```

Comment: The before hook worked for me, but calling the command didn't for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned a simplified script could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e -x 

mvn spring-boot:start
mvn gatling:execute
mvn spring-boot:stop
```

Comment: Thanks for the "start" suggestion, that's what I would lik to do. However this is not working, I get a build success but the gatling tests still notify that the app is not started.

Comment: Seems like I forgot a few things in my pom.xml. I'll try a few things and get back to you.

Comment: This is still not working, after a spring-boot:start, the server does not stay up and running

Answer (score 0):

Patrick's answer gave enough elements to consider using a simple shell script. If you ever encounter that kind of problem, here is the code I wrote :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# ########### FUNCTIONS
trim(){
    [[ "$1" =~ ^[[:space:]]*(.*[^[:space:]])[[:space:]]*$ ]]
    printf "%s" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
}

# ########### MAIN PROGRAM

# ------ First, launch the spring-boot app in background
mvn spring-boot:run &

# ------ Then, wait for it to be correctly initialized

portExtracted=`awk '/server/,/port/' ./src/main/resources/application.yml | cut -d ":" -f 2`
portToListenTo=`trim ${portExtracted}`

i=0
maxCounter=100
while [[ ! $(lsof -i :"$portToListenTo") ]] && [ ${i} -lt ${maxCounter} ]
do
    echo 'Waiting for spring-boot app to be up and running.'
    sleep 2
    i=$[$i+1]
done

mvn gatling:execute
```

You'll have to adapt it to your needs though : change the path to your configuration file and the awk command to dynamically extract your app's port.

Any suggestion to enhance the script is appreciated.

**EDIT :** I also replaced the spring-boot maven plugin description with the following in the pom :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

    <configuration>
        <mainClass>aperture.config.SpringBootApertureTestingConfiguration</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>post-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This way the app is started before the gatling tests are run. To do this, simply run the `mvn verify` command. It also works with `mvn clean install` if you don't skip the tests.

Hope this helps !